# How to translate url in Django?

Tags: python, django, translation, django-urls, django-i18n

This is my `django-project` below to translate from English to French. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-views.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app2
 └-locale
    └-fr
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.po
          └-django.mo
```

And, this is `core/settings.py` below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French'))
)
```

And, [gettext()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) is used to translate `Test` to `Examen` in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def test(request):     # ↓ Here ↓
    return HttpResponse(_("Test"))
```

And, `hello/world/` path for `test()` is set to `urlpatterns` in `my_app1/urls.py` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "my_app1"

urlpatterns = [
        # ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓
    path("hello/world/", views.test, name="test")
]
```

And, `my_app1/` path for `my_app1` is set to `urlpatterns` with [i18n_patterns()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
        # ↓ Here ↓
    path("my_app1/", include('my_app1.urls'))
)
```

And, `"Anglais"`, `"Français"` and `"Examen"` are set for `"English"`, `"French"` and `"Test"` respectively in `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` as shown below:

```
# "locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"

...

#: .\core\settings.py:140
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais" # Here

#: .\core\settings.py:141
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français" # Here

#: .\my_app1\views.py:5
msgid "Test"
msgstr "Examen" # Here

...
```

Then, I could translate from English to French as shown below:

```
http://localhost:8000/fr/my_app1/hello/world/
```

[image]

Now, how can I translate the English url above to the French url below?

```
http://localhost:8000/fr/mon_app1/bonjour/monde/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) and replace `"hello/world/"` with `_("hello/world/")` as shown below. *For the path, `gettext_lazy()` works but [gettext()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) doesn't work and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418) explaining how to translate in Django in detail:

```py
# "my_app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ # Here

app_name = "my_app1"

urlpatterns = [
        # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓
    path(_("hello/world/"), views.test, name="test")
    # path("hello/world/", views.test, name="test")
]
```

Then, use `gettext_lazy()` and replace `"my_app1/"` with `_("my_app1/")` as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ # Here

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
        # ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓
    path(_("my_app1/"), include('my_app1.urls'))
    # path("my_app1/", include('my_app1.urls'))
)
```

Then, run the command below:

```
django-admin makemessages -l fr
```

Then, add `"mon_app1/"` and `"bonjour/monde/"` for `"my_app1/"` and `"hello/world/"` respectively as shown below:

```
# "locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"

...

#: .\core\settings.py:140
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais"

#: .\core\settings.py:141
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français"

#: .\core\urls.py:20
msgid "my_app1/"
msgstr "mon_app1/" # Here

#: .\my_app1\urls.py:8
msgid "hello/world/"
msgstr "bonjour/monde/" # Here

#: .\my_app1\views.py:5
msgid "Test"
msgstr "Examen"

...
```

Then, run the command below:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

Now, you can translate the English url to the French url as shown below:

```
http://localhost:8000/fr/mon_app1/bonjour/monde/
```

[image]

In addition, I don't know how to translate the url in Django Admin so I asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76494207/how-to-translate-the-url-in-django-admin) about it.